# Angular 4 primeng onChange is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, primeng

Currently I'm implementing a search method to search from two dropdown column.
We selecting the first column and then selecting the second column. We have 2 silos and 4 shops, selecting the first silo then it will show 2 shops which siloId is 1 and selecting the second silo will show the rest 2 shops with siloId 2. However, no matter how do I modify the onChange($event), the (onChange)="onChange($event.value) seems never work.

**Here is my .ts code**

```
 /*Here is my .ts code*/<br> constructor(
      private router: Router ) {
       this.silos = [
        {label: 'North ASSEMBLY SILO', value:{Id: '1'}},
        {label: 'South ASSEMBLY SILO', value:{Id: '2'}},
        ];           
       this.shops = [          
        {label: 'Assembly N', value:{siloId: '1', Id: '1'}},
        {label: 'Assembly NN', value:{siloId: '1', Id: '2'}},
        {label: 'Assembly S', value:{siloId: '2', Id: '3'}},
        {label: 'Assembly SS', value:{siloId: '2', Id: '4'}},
        ];
                 }
        onChange($event){
          if(event) {
             // No matter what I do, this seems doesn't work....
        }
    }
```

**And this is my .html code**

```
        <div class="ui-grid-col-3" >   
        <b>DROP DOWN TO SELECT SILOS</b>
        <p-dropdown [options]="silos" [(ngModel)]="selcetedShop" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter = "true" (onChange)="onChange($event)">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-3" >    
        <b>DROP DOWN TO SELECT SHOPS</b>
        <p-dropdown [options]="shops" [(ngModel)]="selectedSilo" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter ="true">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bad tagging, please correct it. One of the tags is totally unrelated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **`(ngModelChange)`**

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="silos" [(ngModel)]="selcetedShop" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter = "true" (ngModelChange)="onChange(selcetedShop)" >
```

Comment: it should pass the selectedShop to your onchange function

Comment: Thx, and I want to confirm how can I get the id in this {label: 'North ASSEMBLY SILO', value:{Id: '1'}},

Comment: just get selcetedShop.value.Id

Comment: please give a solution for formControlName because i am not using [(ngModel)]

Comment: oh. its done using `(onSelect)="changeCountry(registerForm.controls['country'].value)"`